# How to achieve 'inner' zip?

Tags: numpy, reshape

The shape of the two arrays `x` and `y` is `(a,b)`. How do I get a combined array of shape `(a,b,2)`?

My current solution is

```
z = np.zeros((a,b,2))
z[:,:,0] = x
z[:,:,1] = y
```

Is it possible to achieve this without creating a new array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.dstack`:

```
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: a = np.random.normal(size=(4,6))
In [4]: b = np.random.normal(size=(4,6))

In [5]: np.dstack((a,b)).shape
Out[5]: (4, 6, 2)
```

And a comparison:

```
In [10]: d = np.dstack((a,b))  
In [11]: c = np.zeros((4,6,2))
In [12]: c[:,:,0] = a
In [13]: c[:,:,1] = b

In [14]: np.allclose(c,d)
Out[14]: True
```

Comment: This still "creates a new array" but I don't think it's possible to avoid, unless `x` and `y` were contiguous to start with.

Comment: The `dstack` method is actually a little bit slower in my case. It's 1.42s vs. 1.29s.